# Dart: Assign function type with multiple "arguments" to Type variable

Tags: dart

I am struggling with assigning a function type with multiple "arguments" to a Type variable. I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I can define a type using typedef:

`typedef foo = int Function(int)`

but can't assign the same type to a Type variable:

`Type foo = int Function(int)`

The reason I don't want to use typedef is that you can only use it in the global scope.

Does someone know how to solve this or why it doesn't work. I appreciate any answers ☺️

Comment: What are you going to use this `Type` object for? They are not really that useful in lot of cases. E.g. you can't use a `Type` instance in a `if (something is type)` statement.

Comment: For type checking in a unit test

Comment: @Anton Can you provide an example of what you're testing?  Furthermore, "The reason I don't want to use typedef is that you can only use it in the global scope." Why is that important, especially for a test?

Answer (score 1):

A function type is not a type *literal*, so you can't use it as an expression.

It's very easy to get around that these days:

```dart
typedef typeof<T> = T;
```

and

```dart
Type foo = typeOf<int Function(int)>;
```

Now, I don't recommend using `Type` objects for much of anything. Especially not in unit tests.
The only thing you can do with type objects is check for equality. If the type is just a bit off, it won't be equal. For example `Object? Function(Object?)` is not equal to `dynamic Function(dynamic)`, even though they are mutual subtypes.

If you want to check that a function is an `int Function(int)`, use `is int Function(int)`.
If you want to check that a type parameter is bound to `int Function(int)`, I don't know if the test package has a simple way to do that, but I'd use a helper function like:

```dart
bool isType<T1, T2> => <T1 Function(T1)>[] is List<T2 Function(T2)>;
```

This checks that `T1` is a super- and sub-type of `T2` at the same time, even if it's not *exactly* the same type. That's a much safer test to make than "precisely the same type".